# Moving a 2D object up & down y axis within certain limits

Tags: unity, c#, movement

This was originally written to move a 2D object along  the negative x axis.

Now I also want to move the same 2D object along the y axis (up and down within certain limit and at different speed than the x axis movement) while the movement along the negative x axis continues as before.

So far I have the x axis movement working the way I want, but on the y axis it goes either up or down without a limit. I don't know how to use `Mathf.Clamp` in this scenario, that is my problem.

```
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 1.5f;
    public float yspeed = 0.5f;

    void Update()
    {
        MoveObstacle();
    }

    void MoveObstacle()
    {
        transform.Translate(
              -speed * Time.deltaTime,
              yspeed * Time.deltaTime, 
              0
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at Unity's documentation of `Mathf.Clamp` ? Is there something specific you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want either something like this:

```
var newPosition = transform.position;
newPosition.x -= xSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
newPosition.y += ySpeed * Time.deltaTime;

newPosition.y = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.y, yMin, yMax);

transform.position = newPosition;
```

This will continue moving with `ySpeed` until it hits either `yMin` or `yMax` and hold at that height until you change the `ySpeed` variable to go the other way.

Or, if you want it to oscillate on its own, without changing the speed variable to tell it when to switch, you can use something like...

```
newPosition.y = 0.5f * (yMin + yMax)
               +0.5f * (yMax - yMin) * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency);
```

This will give you a smooth wave between `yMin` and `yMax`, which you can make tighter or looser by adjusting the `frequency` variable. You can use `Mathf.PingPong` in a similar way to get a pointy saw wave instead of a smooth sine wave.